# Rails Namespaced Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I have a controller `Api::V1::UsersController` in app/controllers/api/v1.
I have a helper module `Api::V1::ErrorHelper` in app/helpers/api/v1.

I want to access the helper modules's methods inside the controller. So, I called the controller's helper method, passing it the module:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController

  helper Api::V1::ErrorHelper

  #other code
end
```

But when I access one of the helper methods (respond_with_error) inside the controller I get following exception:

```
undefined method `respond_with_error' for #<Api::V1::UsersController:0x007fad1b189578>
```

How can I access this helper from the controller?

(I am using Rails 3.2)

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Helpers are mixed in the view, not in the controller. For example, if you have the following helper

```
module Authentication
  def current_user
    # ...
  end
end
```

and you include it in any controller

```
helper Authentication
```

calling `current_user` from an action will raise an undefined method error.

If you want to make some methods available to the view and the controller, you need a different approach. Define the methods and include the module as a normal module.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include Authentication
end
```

and make the methods available as helpers.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include Authentication

  helper_method :current_user
end
```

You can also take advantage of the `included` hook.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include Authentication
end

module Authentication
  def self.included(base)
    base.include Helpers
    base.helper  Helpers
  end

  module Helpers
    def current_user
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`helper` includes that module in your views, to include it at your controller just 'include Api::V1::ErrorHelper`.

But including view helpers in a controller is not a good idea, you should probably place this somewhere else (your `lib` directory, maybe) and not call it a helper, since it isn't a view helper, but a controller helper.